# How to work with @SequenceGenerator in Spring if your ID column in of type VARCHAR?

Tags: oracle, jpa, entity, sequence, varchar

My oracle table has id column defined as of type varchar2(10). It is because I intend to append a string value to the generated number from a sequence defined in the database.

What is the ideal way to work with @SequenceGenerator in this scenario?